# Update one field or insert many if not exists

Tags: mongodb

Upsert functionality is great in update method, but it seems it has one big disadvantage, and I cannot find a reasonable solution to it.

The problem is that I want to update only one field if there are results found matching the query criteria, but none rows found, I want to insert a lot of fields.

For example if **find( {name: John, surname: Connor })** returns result, I want to set only new age for him like **{ age: 33 }**, but if no results found, I want to insert a lot of fields, something like **{ name: John, surname: Connor, age: 32, role: commander, character: cautious, hobby: 'kill terminators' }**

Is there a pretty way to achieve this on one query? Or the only solution is straighforward one, meaning find, check how many results found, and based on it insert or update?

**EDIT:** I made an addition to explain the need of ability to make this in one step. The solution to make it in two steps (first find, and then insert/update) is good when having one worked to find and update/insert, but this will fail when having like 1000 of workers that will try to do it - in result I may have a lot of John Connors in the database (when first couple of workers will find no results and all of them inserts a new row) unless I make an unique index to Name-Surname pair (somehow). But I am looking for solution not to do so.

Comment: I did same in my project and i use the way first it checks if there isn't record then insert and if there is then update it, so both queries but only one will run after passing through my check

Comment: I think DB should not implements this logic. It's only logic of YOUR programm and why it should be within database? You should check if find query return anything (here you can use limit 1 to check only existence if you need) and execute one or another update query. It's not logic for DB...

Comment: The problem is that using upsert makes you, lets say, thread safe when you have 1000 workers that wants to upsert. Using two steps (find and update/insert) may result having more than one JC unless you set Name and Surname as unique index (but I do not how to set them to be unique only as a pair of name-surname unless to make one extra field that connects them and make it unique)

Comment: Doesn't [`$setOnInsert`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#up._S_setOnInsert) exist to let you do *exactly* this? Note to self: check this out later and give an answer involving `$setOnInsert` if appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to match on enough criteria to select the specific document, using the exact values present in the document, and then send **all** data which would be necessary to create the document if it didn't already exist. Additionally, you'd need to specify the [`upsert`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) option to create the document if it didn't exist.

```
update( {name: "John", surname: "Connor" }, 
        { $set :
             {name: "John", surname: "Connor", age: 32, terminated: false}},
        { upsert: true })
```

Make sure that you understand the nature of using `upsert` as well. The query needs to depend on a unique field, or you could end up with multiple documents with matched data.

> **Warning** To avoid inserting the same document more than once, only use
>   upsert: true if the query field is uniquely indexed

MongoDB does not support a way to conditionally update only portions of a document depending on the results of a query. There's **not** something that would allow:

```
updateIf(query, updateIfTrue, updateIfFalse, options)
```

To update portions selectively, you'll need to perform multiple steps or update the entire document by using `$set`.

Comment: This will also fail as @Jinxcat solution when I want to change only one variable, when two of them are really changed. Due to this if I send all data necessary to create new row, two new values will be stored as well, but this is not what I want.

Comment: I don't understand. "two of them?" What's "Them"? I've added a bit more to say what doesn't exist.

Comment: Imagine we have a rows like _id and 6 more variables (lets name them var1,var2, .. var6) in collection. From some system I receive new 6 variables value. To store what I need I search by var1 and var2. If found (meaning there is a row already in collection with exact values in var1 and var2), I need to update only var3 value of it leaving the rest as they were before. If not found, I need to insert a new row with all 6 variables. So if I receive new var3 and var5 for current var1 and var2, I only need to update var3 value, but not var3 and var5.This is what I mean "one of them".

Comment: As I added to my answer, that's not supported.

Comment: yes, I can see that now. Marked as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the desired functionality by matching with the full document attributes, **except** the attribute you want to update. Example below:

Insert the only document in collection:

```
db.collection.insert({ name: "John", surname: "Connor", age: 32, role: "commander", character: "cautious", hobby: "kill terminators" })
```

Now

```
db.collection.find({"name" : "John", "surname" : "Connor", "role" : "commander", "character" : "cautious", "hobby" : "kill terminators" })
```

returns:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52fc9a02d342217e6262aa28"), "name" : "John", "surname" : "Connor", "age" : 32, "role" : "commander", "character" : "cautious", "hobby" : "kill terminators" }
```

The update statement

```
db.collection.update({"name" : "John", "surname" : "Connor", "role" : "commander", "character" : "cautious", "hobby" : "kill terminators" },{$set:{age:33}}, { upsert: true })
```

updates existing document's attribute 'age':

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52fc9a02d342217e6262aa28"), "name" : "John", "surname" : "Connor", "age" : 33, "role" : "commander", "character" : "cautious", "hobby" : "kill terminators" }
```

If you run the exact same update statement changing the name (hence, the find query will not find an existing document):

```
db.collection.update({"name" : "Robot", "surname" : "Connor", "role" : "commander", "character" : "cautious", "hobby" : "kill terminators" },{$set:{age:33}}, { upsert: true })
```

"Robot Connor" document will be created, with age 33, and you end up with two documents in your collection:

```
db.collection.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("52fc9a02d342217e6262aa28"), "name" : "John", "surname" : "Connor", "age" : 33, "role" : "commander", "character" : "cautious", "hobby" : "kill terminators" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52fc9a5f56641f5e1b883677"), "age" : 33, "character" : "cautious", "hobby" : "kill terminators", "name" : "Robot", "role" : "commander", "surname" : "Connor" }
```

Note: I don't believe the extra attributes on the query parameter of update  have a performance impact.

Comment: I cannot match all attributes because in my example I will find on records (because age is now: 32) and in result new John Connor will be inserted.

Comment: Yes you can. You just ignore age on your search pattern. See updated answer.

Comment: This could work when only age really changed, but this will not work if age and hobby changed, but I want to update only age. This is why I strictly want to be able to define what to search, what to update if found and what to insert if not. It seems that the only reasonable way is to add compound unique index on Name and Surname (to ensure that no double row will be created simultaneously) and just make regular find + conditional insert/update based on find result.

Comment: This will work fine if both age and hobby changed. As long as you update both of them. Why wouldn't you want to keep your documents updated?! A unique index on Name+Surname will make your system incapable of handling 2 people with the same name...

Comment: yes, but, as I mentioned, when two of them changed, but I just want to update one of them, it will not. Unfortunately I have a reason to update only one of them, this is why the question was raised. And yes, unique index will make incapable of having two JC, but is is also ok.